# Hide commandbutton to print document via a created button

Tags: vba, printing, ms-office, commandbutton, word-2013

This is my first post on here, I will try to be as clear as possible :)

I'm creating a Microsoft Word form for users to fill in, this form is protected and only the forms can be filled in the rest of the document is protected with the password: "mypass"

I want to have a button on the document it self wich prints the active document. What I did is create a print button into a “drawing” Textbox ( Insert | Textbox ) as stated [here](http://word.mvps.org/faqs/tblsfldsfms/HidePrintButton.htm).

This Print button must be hidden so it's not visible on the document when it's printed.

Here is the code:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()

If ActiveDocument.ProtectionType <> wdNoProtection Then
ActiveDocument.Unprotect Password:="mypass"
End If

With ActiveDocument
    .Shapes(1).Visible = msoFalse
    .PrintOut Copies:=1
    .Shapes(1).Visible = msoTrue
End With

ActiveDocument.Protect Type:=wdAllowOnlyFormFields, Password:="mypass"

End Sub
```

When I click the print button in protective mode nothing happens, when I turn off protective mode I get this error:

> Error 4641 at run.
>
> ToolsProtectDocument statement is currently disabled

To summarize:

The Print button I created does not work when protective mode is enabled.
When protective mode is disabled I get the error that the ToolsProtectDocument statement is currently disabled.

I want to have a procted form that can be filled in and be printed from the form itself without the print button being visable on the printed form.

Does anyone have a clue?